# Export articles in recent changes to an xml dump

Tags: xml, mediawiki

i am looking for a solution to dump (xml format, incl. templates) each article how was edited in the last hour.

i started with imacro for firefox. Getting the list of articles are now fine. Currently i have troube with article name, which includes spaces or german umlaut.

e.g.Eidgen%C3%B6ssische_Konstruktionswerkst%C3%A4tte_K%2BW_C-35

How can i convert i to "real" article names?

Answer (score 1):

The title you are seeing is encoded for use in a URL. Your programming language should provide a standard method for decoding these, e.g. "urldecode" in PHP, "decodeURIComponent" in JavaScript, "urllib2.quote" in Python, etc.

But you shouldn't need to do this at all if you fetch the titles of the changed pages via the MediaWiki API. See this query for Wikipedia, for example: https://de.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=recentchanges&format=xml

Comment: thx. at moment imacros has no urldecode. i found an outer solution. The title is saved (already encoded) in a title attribut to all links on the recent changed page.

Comment: Using the api works only on newer Wikis as longs as this is not disabled. So i prefer a general solution. And on big problem is, that the xml has to reworked to using the importer.